# How to have HTML button activate python script?

Tags: python, html, linux, flask, raspberry-pi

My project is to have a user use a website to control a raspberry pi camera. The button on the website will run a script to take a photo on the camera. The script works fine as its own exe, but when I try to incorporate it into the app.py code it doesn't work. I've tried various solutions to no avail.
I am extremely new to linux/html/python, so I'm struggling a lot here.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="container">

<div><img src="https://scontent-dfw5-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/52914705_308217033137888_3861578789158912000_n.png?_nc_cat=101&_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-1.xx&oh=b067e9981fe2bbf6903d034ea33108bf&oe=5D1E4F7C" alt="Logo" height="40%" width="40%">

<br><br> <p>Thank you for using Photobooth Pi! 
<br>Click the button below to start a countdown.</p>

<form action="/pic" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Take a pic">
</form>

</div>            
<div class="footer">
    <p><strong> COPYRIGHT © 2019 PHOTOBOOTH PI. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</strong></p>
</div>
```

PYTHON/FLASK CODE:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import time
import picamera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/pic', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pic():
    "camera = picamera.PiCamera()"
    "camera.rotation = 90"
    "camera.stat_preview()"
    "time.sleep(5)"
    "camera.capture('tester.jpg')"
    "camera.stop_preview()"
    return        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Pi's IP Address
    app.run(debug=True, host='10.0.83.149')
```

The button doesn't work, it takes me to a debug screen. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code is well written overall. The error you encounter comes from the fact that your function does not return any response. Or to be more precise, your `pic` function ends with an implicit `return None`, which does not work with Flask and that generates an error. Try to return something, for example: `return "ok"`

---

**EDIT**

In accordance with the clarifications made and my last comment, here is an approach of solution to your problem:

```
@app.route('/pic', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pic():
    os.system("sudo python pic.py")
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! When adding an "ok" to return, I just get a white screen with ok written on it. No picture taken. The terminal says "POST /pic HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: The question was to make the button work and avoid the error that was displayed. That's what I answered. Now what you are trying to do is to upload the photo taken on a web page. Flask allows it. The procedure here is: you store the photo taken in a directory and you write a Python/Flask function that will look for the photo in this directory and display it on the web page. [here is a link that explains everything there is to know about uploading files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/).

Comment: I'm definitely going to use that link later in the project, thanks. But my problem right now is that the python script is not running when I click the button. The button returns "ok", but no picture is taken on the Pi. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough!

Comment: You said that your photo capture script runs well when it's isolated ... here is a tip that I tested a long time ago: the python `os.system` method allows you to execute a linux command. So instead of writing in flask the capture code, you can keep it separate in a file (**pic.py**), and call the script via `os.system` (`os.system("sudo python pic.py")`)

Comment: Look what I added to my answer above.